# How do I create and lock a single photo album in ios10?

Tags: iphone, ipad, photos

I am looking to lock a single album on my phone within my iOS albums, where I can store things that...

- I to remain permanently on my iPhone/iPad
- I don't want saved anywhere other than in my backups
- I don't want my kids to accidentally see
- I don't want to re-save to google photos, one drive etc. repeatedly...
- That remains the one and only place, besides a back-up that specific images remain.

Answer (score 1):

## You can't lock the photos, but you *can* hide them.

Hiding photos is a simple enough process. Start by opening up photos and selecting all the photos you wish to hide.

Now, click the share button and scroll through the bottom section looking for an item labeled 'Hide'.

Now, the only place that the photos are accessible is in **Photos > Albums > Hidden**. There's not even a preview so the photos stay extra hidden.

[image]

Unfortunately, there's no native (as you requested) way to lock these photos with a PIN, but now the only way to see them is to find the Hidden album.

All photos in the Hidden album are not shown in **Moments, Collections, and Years**. Until iOS 11 and macOS 10.13 *High Sierra,* Hidden items will still appear in auto-generated albums, like selfies, screenshots, etc.

Comment: Hidden photos are only hidden in **Moments**, **Collections** and **Years** views. They remain visible within whatever albums they are added to. And until iOS 11 / macOS 10.13 High Sierra, they are also visible inside automatic albums (eg. the *Selfies* album).

Comment: @Phong, thanks for letting me know, I'll update my answer. I was just putting in what iOS told me when I tried it :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put images into the Notes app. Those can be locked and will sync across your iCloud-enabled devices in the same manner.

It's not as robust as the Photos app but may meet your needs for easy access to synced, locked content.